# Is there a human language that has months ordered alphabetically?

Tags: sorting, culture, isodate

So I like datestrings in ISO format ie 2021-12-25 - it means you can just apply a simple sort and dates are in the right order.

But sometimes it is nice to see months as English rather trying to remember if October is 8th or ninth or tenth month. (maybe its just me).

So 2021-Dec-25 is nice to read *but* I lose that sort quality - this date would now appear *before* Thanksgiving on 2021-Nov-25.

So I was wondering if there was a human language that can do both - is there a language where January comes before February in that language's alphabet.  For example French fails here (Janvier > Fevrier).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this ain't programming

Comment: Are you going to switch the language of your UI just so you can sort dates?  That's kind of silly.

Comment: P.S. the thing that makes ISO-8601 so awesome is that it's language agnostic.

Comment: Even though it is an odd question, I think the link with ISO dates makes it borderline on-topic. The answer below is certainly nice and involves programming. I am voting to reopen.

Comment: @JohnColeman ISO sidesteps the problem completely by eliminating names entirely and using only numbers.  I can't see a situation where an accurate answer to this question would be useful to anybody.

Comment: You could go with a compromise that includes both the month number and name: `2021-12(Dec)-25`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's *query* the cultures: for each culture we get months' names and check if they are sorted (we compare original names with the *sorted* names).

**C# code:**

```
  var result = CultureInfo
    .GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    .Where(ci => ci.DateTimeFormat
       .MonthNames
       .Where(month => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(month))
       .Where(month => !Regex.IsMatch(month, "^M[0-9]+$"))
       .Any())
    .Where(ci => ci.DateTimeFormat
       .MonthNames
       .Where(month => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(month))
       .SequenceEqual(ci
          .DateTimeFormat
          .MonthNames
          .Where(month => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(month))
          .OrderBy(month => month)))
    .OrderBy(ci => ci.Name)
    .Select(ci => $"{ci.Name} ({ci.EnglishName})");

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

**Outcome:**

```
  Empty
```

So, there are **no** such (lucky?) cultures on the Earth (at least known to .Net 5)

You can try `AbbreviatedMonthNames`, `MonthGenitiveNames`, but alas: the output will be empty as well.

Comment: It would be interesting to see which culture comes closest, with distance to ideal being measured by the number of swaps needed to sort.